# .htaccess file ineffective at password protecting my xampp directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm totally new to XAMPP and I'm trying to set up the security for it as best as possible.  I understand that it is beneficial to create an .htaccess file to password protect certain directories.  There is a page/script that is built into xampp available at `http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php` that will generate one for you in the /htdocs/xampp directory.  However, after I've gone and done this, I'm still not prompted for a password when I visit my site at `http://localhost/xampp`. I thought I should've been prompted for a username and password here? This is a difficult problem to search answers for so I apologize if this has been answered already.

I've made sure to close/re-open my browser and delete all history/cache/cookies.  I also restarted the Apache service after creating the htaccess file.

the .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "xampp user"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\security\xampp.users"
require valid-user
```

`C:\xampp\security\xampp.users` is a valid file and it contains the username I setup and an encrypted password.

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy your .htaccess file to the htdocs directory:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\.htaccess

I hope it works ;)

Looks like .htaccess doesn't work on the htdocs\xampp directory.